# Express.js Server: PUT Request using Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, put

I have a working Node/Express server and I'm using it to do requests via localhost to an external API. As you can see in my example code, I'm using `node-fetch` for my basic GET requests.

For every request, I prepare a `const url = BASE_URL` in advance, needed for the actual external server request.

But I'm getting stuck at my `PUT-Request` as I can't using `node-fetch`. So what do I have to do, to notify my Express server with the actual URL for the PUT-Request?

The PUT-Request doesn't work til here.

```
/* Route: Get Appointment it's availability times */
app.get('/availability/times/:id/:date/:locationId', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var date = req.params.date;
  var locationId = req.params.locationId;
  const url = BASE_URL + '/availability/times?appointmentTypeID=' + id + '&date=' + date + '&calendarID=' + locationId;;
  fetch(url, {
      mode: "no-cors",
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'content-type'
      },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      res.json(json);
    });
});

app.put('/appointments/:id/cancel', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  const url = BASE_URL + '/appointments/' + id + '/cancel';
  res.send(req.body)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that `fetch` is undefined in your put request, make sure you are requiring it at the top before any routes `var fetch = require('node-fetch')`. For your base url, you should store that in a config file. Create a file called `config.js` that looks something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  'BASE_URL': 'yoururlhere'
}
```

then require this in your express server `var config = require('pathToConfig');` and you can use it by specifying `config.BASE_URL`

If that doesn't help, please be more specific with what your actual problem is